# Why does my 'typewriter' iterator print a string in the wrong order?

Tags: javascript, iterator

Apologies if this is daft question, but I can't understand why the following code logs the letters from a string in a seemingly random order:

```js
const aString = "hello, this is a string";
const iterator = aString[Symbol.iterator]();

var typewriter =
  setInterval(() => {
    if (iterator.next().done) {
      clearInterval(typewriter);
    } else {
      console.log(iterator.next().value);
    }
  }, 200);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I can't understand why the following code logs the letters from a string in a seemingly random order:

It doesn't, it *skips* every other character. That's because you are calling `.next` twice in every iteration. `if (iterator.next().done)` will consume a character. Only call `.next()` once:

```js
const aString = "hello, this is a string";
const iterator = aString[Symbol.iterator]();

var typewriter =
  setInterval(() => {
    const next = iterator.next();
    if (next.done) {
      clearInterval(typewriter);
    } else {
      console.log(next.value);
    }
  }, 200);
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. That makes sense. I'm too much of an amateur to know why that happens, though. If you had time I would really appreciate help understanding that?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: At first, I didn't understand why `if (iterator.next().done)` would constitute a next() call. Seems totally ridiculous now that I think about it but in my head, it didn't make sense that it would 'count', given that my intent was just to use it as a condition for the if...else statement. I am very new to programming and I am not used to there being no implied meaning in things :P